# Употребление слов "представление" и "предоставление"

Tags: употребление-слов

«Срок представления оферт» или «Срок предОставления оферт»?

Answer (score 2):

Оферта является предложением юридического или физического лица заключить договор с указанием конкретных условий . При этом данное предложение может иметь любой формат: письмо, факс, телеграмма или проект договора.

Представить-доставить,предъявить, сообщить (список,доказательство)

Предоставить - отдать в пользование или дать право.

Письмо, факс,проект договора мы преОставляем, как и оферту предоставляем - даём возможность воспользоваться предложением.(обычно в какой-то определённый срок)

Answer (score 2):

Контекст нужен, желательно - побольше.

Эти обороты имеют разный смысл, в принципе достаточно актуальными могут быть оба, хотя строгому официальному языку ни тот ни другой не соответствуют. В последнее время наиболее частое использование оферты - т.н. публичная оферта (или публичный договор-оферта). Это предложение, направленное на массового потребителя, которое вывешивается в доступном месте (на сайте, как правило) и как правило не требует от второй стороны подписания отдельного контракта (заключение по факту).

В связи с этим наиболее правдоподобны следующие варианты:

"Срок пред**о**ставления оферты": 
a) время, в которое желающий может воспользоваться офертой (собери с 1.05 до 31.30 пять купонов от наших больших зеленых невтыкалок - и получи бесплатно одну маленькую красную).

б) время действия ранее заключенного договора оферты или его части (на купленный в период рождественских распродаж комбайн срок гарантии - 2 года).

в) Срок, в который предлагающая сторона должна выполнить условия (оплаченный товар доставляется покупателю не позже 72 часов с момента заключения сделки).

По большому счету б) и в) совсем маловероятно.

"Срок пре**дс**тавления оферты":

Обусловленный генеральным договором (или договором о намерениях) срок, в который должен быть заключен частный договор с конкретными условиями.

Но, повторюсь, в официальном документе я бы избегал обоих выражений. 
Лучше сказать "срок действия оферты", "срок предоставления услуг по договору оферты" и проч. - в зависимости от смысла.

Comment: @behemothus, у вас бывают забавные опечатки: "которое вышивается в доступном месте". Я так и представила себе эту вышивку. ;-))

Comment: Бывают. Спасибо. 
Горбатого могила правит. А сейчас ещё и с интернетом мучаюсь...

Answer (score 1):

Я не сильна в банковской терминологии, но, по-моему, "представление" — это, когда вы что-то предъявляете кому-то, а вот "предоставление" — скорее, передаете в пользование.
Поэтому смотрите, что Вам больше подходит.