# Пред(о)ставление документов и информации - как правильно?

Tags: грамотная-речь, выбор-слов, паронимы

Вместе с тем предлагаем срок для пред(о)ставления региональным оператором уполномоченному органу госвласти субъекта РФ документов и информации установить в 5 рабочих дней.

Comment: А вопрос в чем?

Comment: Предоставления или представления?

Comment: Ответ здесь: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/26632/%d0%a3%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5

Comment: В данном контексте "предоставить документы и информацию?"

Comment: В данном контексте "документы представляют, а информацию предоставляют". Разве не так? Можно объединить в данном предложении "предоставить"?

Answer (score 2):

Придется повторить то, что написано в ответе на старый вопрос:
[Употребление слов "представление" и "предоставление"](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/26632/%d0%a3%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5).

Эти обороты имеют разный смысл.
Представить — доставить, предъявить, сообщить (список, доказательство).
Предоставить — отдать в пользование или дать право.

Автор должен решить, что он хочет: чтобы ему предъявили документы и информацию или отдали для использования. А может документы нужно предъявить, а информацию отдать для использования?

Вот пример, придуманный мною. Проверяющий потребовал немедленно **представить** (выложить на стол) информацию и документы, а затем потребовал **предоставить** (в его распоряжение) информацию и документы для дополнительной экспертизы.

Из Нацкорпуса:

> Это обусловлено тем, что цель составления консолидированной отчетности ― **представить** информацию об активах, обязательствах и финансовом положении Группы как единой организации с точки зрения внешних пользователей отчетности. [Формирование учетной политики организации (2004) // «Бухгалтерский учёт», 2004.12.06]
>
> К борьбе подключилась и законодательная власть ― Госдума направила Касьянову парламентский запрос с просьбой «принять меры по обеспечению эффективного управления ВЭБом переданными ему средствами Пенсионного фонда, а также **представить** информацию о мерах по недопущению использования Внешэкономбанком указанных средств для погашения и обслуживания государственного долга»… [Борис Вишневский. Пенсионная рулетка // «Московские новости», 2003]
>
> Национальный банк Украины (НБУ) потребовал от банков **предоставить** информацию о направленных ими в четвертом квартале 2002 года в органы по борьбе с организованной преступностью сообщениях о лицах, проводящих сомнительные операции. [Банковские новости (2003) // «Финансы и кредит», 2003.02.03]
>
> Не секрет, что и раньше представители ФСБ периодически обращались к интернет-компаниям с требованием **предоставить** информацию о содержании электронных писем и IP-адресов телефонов, с которых осуществлялась пересылка сообщений. [Андрей Уранов. ФСБ ужесточает контроль за «почтовыми» интернет-компаниями (2003) // «ПОЛИТКОМ. РУ», 2003.04.25]

Answer (score 0):

Представление (прокурора) — это акт реагирования на нарушение законодательства.

В вашем случае речь идёт о предъявлении (пересылке, доставке) документа.

Правильно: предоставление.